# Table inside a table in R / dataframe inside dataframe in R

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a dataframe which has table inside a table. Final objective is to display the same table in RShiny.

[image]

So in the above image

dataframe 1 is `data.frame(df$Notes_dept_mapping, df$Status)`

But `df$Notes_dept_mapping[1]<- data.frame(df2$1, df$2)`

This wouldn't work. I tried to employ the second dataframe df2 as a matrix. Even then I was not able to accomplish my objective.

Comment: can you clarify why you want to do this? Since data.frames are lists, you can technically embed one into the other using `AsIs`, but I don't think that's the solution to your Shiny problem.

Comment: I want a display of tables inside tables and render it. I am out of ideas.

Comment: If you're in Shiny, you could assemble them in HTML. `xtable`/the like may have a way, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nest(), which is part of `library(tidyverse)`.

The code below creates a `tibble` that has the matrix in the first column and the value '2' in the second column.

```r
raw_data <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(3,5, 4,6), nrow=2))
colnames(raw_data) <- c("var1","var2")
newrow <- data.frame(raw_data, status=2) %>% 
   group_by(status) %>% 
   nest %>% 
   relocate(data, status) %>% 
   rename(`Notes (dept mapping)`=data)
```